# How to store id's of different objects in below mentioned JSON Response in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

[
{
"postId": 1,
"id": 1,
"name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
"email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
"body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
},
{
"postId": 1,
"id": 2,
"name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
"email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
"body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
},
{
"postId": 1,
"id": 3,
"name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
"email": "Nikita@garfield.biz",
"body": "quia molestiae reprehenderit quasi aspernatur\naut expedita occaecati aliquam eveniet laudantium\nomnis quibusdam delectus saepe quia accusamus maiores nam est\ncum et ducimus et vero voluptates excepturi deleniti ratione"
},
{
"postId": 1,
"id": 4,
"name": "alias odio sit",
"email": "Lew@alysha.tv",
"body": "non et atque\noccaecati deserunt quas accusantium unde odit nobis qui voluptatem\nquia voluptas consequuntur itaque dolor\net qui rerum deleniti ut occaecati"
},
{
"postId": 1,
"id": 5,
"name": "vero eaque aliquid doloribus et culpa",
"email": "Hayden@althea.biz",
"body": "harum non quasi et ratione\ntempore iure ex voluptates in ratione\nharum architecto fugit inventore cupiditate\nvoluptates magni quo et"
}
]

```html
[
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
    "email": "Nikita@garfield.biz",
    "body": "quia molestiae reprehenderit quasi aspernatur\naut expedita occaecati aliquam eveniet laudantium\nomnis quibusdam delectus saepe quia accusamus maiores nam est\ncum et ducimus et vero voluptates excepturi deleniti ratione"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "name": "alias odio sit",
    "email": "Lew@alysha.tv",
    "body": "non et atque\noccaecati deserunt quas accusantium unde odit nobis qui voluptatem\nquia voluptas consequuntur itaque dolor\net qui rerum deleniti ut occaecati"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "name": "vero eaque aliquid doloribus et culpa",
    "email": "Hayden@althea.biz",
    "body": "harum non quasi et ratione\ntempore iure ex voluptates in ratione\nharum architecto fugit inventore cupiditate\nvoluptates magni quo et"
  }
]
```

Comment: You want an array of all `id`s?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```js
let ar = [
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
    "email": "Nikita@garfield.biz",
    "body": "quia molestiae reprehenderit quasi aspernatur\naut expedita occaecati aliquam eveniet laudantium\nomnis quibusdam delectus saepe quia accusamus maiores nam est\ncum et ducimus et vero voluptates excepturi deleniti ratione"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "name": "alias odio sit",
    "email": "Lew@alysha.tv",
    "body": "non et atque\noccaecati deserunt quas accusantium unde odit nobis qui voluptatem\nquia voluptas consequuntur itaque dolor\net qui rerum deleniti ut occaecati"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "name": "vero eaque aliquid doloribus et culpa",
    "email": "Hayden@althea.biz",
    "body": "harum non quasi et ratione\ntempore iure ex voluptates in ratione\nharum architecto fugit inventore cupiditate\nvoluptates magni quo et"
  }
]

res = ar.map(elem => elem.id)
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#map` with destructuring.

```
const res = arr.map(({id})=>id);
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
    "email": "Nikita@garfield.biz",
    "body": "quia molestiae reprehenderit quasi aspernatur\naut expedita occaecati aliquam eveniet laudantium\nomnis quibusdam delectus saepe quia accusamus maiores nam est\ncum et ducimus et vero voluptates excepturi deleniti ratione"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "name": "alias odio sit",
    "email": "Lew@alysha.tv",
    "body": "non et atque\noccaecati deserunt quas accusantium unde odit nobis qui voluptatem\nquia voluptas consequuntur itaque dolor\net qui rerum deleniti ut occaecati"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "name": "vero eaque aliquid doloribus et culpa",
    "email": "Hayden@althea.biz",
    "body": "harum non quasi et ratione\ntempore iure ex voluptates in ratione\nharum architecto fugit inventore cupiditate\nvoluptates magni quo et"
  }
];
const res = arr.map(({id})=>id);
console.log(res);
```